# A question was chosen as a Hot Network Question simultaneously 26 times, according to the revision history

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, hot-network-questions

[Why is this chapter called “The Lightning Struck Tower”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/236947/revisions) was chosen as a Hot Network Question. Not very odd, but what *is* odd, as you can see, is that this action was recorded 26 times. I checked the timestamps and they are all showing `2020-09-13 01:41:08Z`... so it looks like there is or was an issue with the recording of HNQ entries in associated question's revision history.

Can staff take a look at what happened here?

Comment: Almost as bad as something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrGiO.png) (not a bug).

Comment: Apparently this bug is fixed now, see [Yaakov Ellis's answer on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354731/278659). (Edit: urgh, I posted that as an answer, but the system converted it to a comment. Ah well, the tag and Glorfindel's answer will do.)

Answer (score 10):

This is a (well-)known bug, see my Meta Stack Exchange question [Very hot network questions found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327889/295232). Staff is aware of it, but [the priority is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327889/very-hot-network-questions-found#comment1183753_327889)

> Very low since it doesn't appear to affect actual functionality.

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly this is the first time I've seen it for something that is happening network-wide and for well over a year now. I guess changing page line-height is a higher priority...

Comment: Also posted [specifically about this case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354156/294691)